# How to skip error found in a batch-file and continue executing the command line?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-console

I'm using the Windows Command Processor, (cmd.exe), to scan all the files in a server. My goal is to have a `.txt` file with name files and where they are located, *(for a faster search)*.

This is my code:

```
P:
DIR *.* /P /Q /S > C:\Users\aperea01\eng.TXT

Z:
DIR *.* /P /Q /S > C:\Users\aperea01\CADUsers.TXT

R:
DIR *.* /P /Q /S > C:\Users\aperea01\eng_restricted.TXT
```

The batch-file commits its goal, but if I find a folder I have no access, the batch-file stops working. It does write and save the last found files but can't continue.

Is there a way to skip the `Access denied` error and continue scanning the server?

Thanks in advance.

`P`, `Z` and `R` are some of the mapped network drives in my PC.

Comment: You don't think it's the `/p` switch? Type `dir /?`.

Comment: Hi @Noodles,
`/P` is not the root cause, even if I remove it from the batch-file, after many many files, when it finds a private folder (personal folder with restricted access), the code save the information and exits the CMD (Windows Command Processor).
You were correct on DIR <directory>.

Answer (score 0):

```
(FOR /R "P:\" %G IN (.) DO @PUSHD %G && @DIR /Q & @POPD) >> "C:\Users\aperea01\eng.TXT"
```

This will iterate over all subfolders in `P:\` and only run `DIR /Q` (standard listing with owner) if the command is able to `PUSHD` (change directory) into it. All the output is redirected to `eng.TXT`. Hopefully this will prevent the `Access denied` problem you faced, though I'm unable to replicate the scenario you described.